# Change and Highlight error Message from Really Simple CAPTCHA — WordPress Plugins

Tags: wordpress

I need the help. I have used the Really Simple Captcha Plugin in my project. This plugin is working fine. Now, I have query for validation error message.

When I submit the form without captcha, it does gives me an error. But the error doesn't says why the form wasn't submitted.

The error text should say "Please verify Captcha to submit the contact form"
[image: Change the error image]

So, Please give me solution on same.